# Проблема с RoutedUICommand

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть xaml

```
<local:TestWindowA x:Class="TestEther.TestWindow"
             ******
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}">
    <local:TestWindowA.Menu>
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=Comm}" CommandManager.Executed="MenuItem_Executed" CommandManager.CanExecute="MenuItem_CanExecute"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </local:TestWindowA.Menu>
</local:TestWindowA>
```

Вот код

```
public partial class TestWindow : TestWindowA
{
    private RoutedUICommand _comm;
    public RoutedUICommand Comm
    {
        get { return _comm; }
        set
        {
            _comm = value;
        }
    }

    public TestWindow()
    {
        Comm = new RoutedUICommand("Comm", "comm", GetType());
        //Comm = new RoutedUICommand("Comm", "comm", typeof(EtherTabControl));
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MenuItem_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("comm");
    }

    private void MenuItem_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }
}
```

При запуске я открываю меню и вижу там "Comm". Нажимаю на него, в консоль выводится "comm". Так и было задумано.

Проблема в том, что когда я перевожу фокус на другие элементы окна, команда больше не активна, хотя выполняется `MenuItem_CanExecute` и устанавливает `e.CanExecute = true;`

Comment: А почему вы делаете как-то странно, через `CommandManager.Executed` и `CommandManager.CanExecute`? Обычно делают через `CommandBinding`.

Comment: @VladD, как нашел так и сделал ) Сейчас почитаю про биндинг

Comment: @VladD, нашел инфу на MSDN, но пример там, как обычно, не очень. Легче будет понять, если приведешь пример с реализацией предложенной мной задачи. Я помечу это как ответ.

Comment: @VladD, такая конструкция не работает `<CommandBinding Command="{Binding Comm}" CanExecute="MenuItem_CanExecute" Executed="MenuItem_Executed"/>`, потому что в Command нельзя указывать Binding. получается что я смогу пользоваться только уже предопределенными командами?

Comment: @VladD, все получилось, спасибо. Добавил в ресурсы окна `<RoutedUICommand Text="Comm" x:Key="comm"/>` и использую его через *StaticResource*. Если оформите, отмечу как ответ. :)

Comment: Ну, я только посоветовал делать по-другому :) Так что заслуга не моя.